Determinant of intersection matrix in Heegaard Floer theory
I am having trouble finishing a 'left to the viewer' computation from this Heegaard Floer talk around the 36 minute mark. I will try to summarize the preceding discussion (using slightly different notation), which starts around the 20 minute mark.
Suppose that $H=\left(\{\alpha_i\}_{i=1}^g,\{\beta_i\}_{i=1}^g,\Sigma_g\right)$ is a Heegaard diagram for a closed oriented 3-manifold $Y$. Fix orientations on the alpha and beta curves and let $s(x)\in \{\pm1\}$ denote the intersection sign at $x \in \alpha_i \cap \beta_j$. I believe that in this talk $\#(\alpha_i \cap \beta_j)$ denotes the algebraic intersection number of $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_j$, which I think should then be the sum of all their local intersection signs.
A "generator" of $H$ is an unordered $g$-tuple of intersection points such that each alpha and beta is occupied exactly once. In other words, a generator is a member of $\mathfrak{S}(H)=\{\mathbf{x}=(x_1,\dots,x_g)|x_i \in \alpha_i \cap \beta_{\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}(i)}, \sigma_{\mathbf{x}} \in S_g\}$. Here "$\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}$" is used to emphasize that each generator has an associated permutation. However, I believe that distinct generators can share the same permutation (consider for example Figure 3 here). I'd appreciate if someone could clarify that - this has been confusing me.
Next, for each generator $\mathbf{x}\in \mathfrak{S}(H)$, let $s(\mathbf{x})=\text{sgn}(\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}) \prod_{i=1}^g s(x_i)$. Lastly, let $M(H)$ be the $g \times g$ matrix given by $m_{ij}=\#(\alpha_i \cap \beta_j)$.
The claim I'm trying to prove is $$\sum_{x\in \mathfrak{S}(H)}s(\mathbf{x})=\pm \det M(H).$$
On the right hand side, we have
\begin{align} \det M(H) &=\sum_{\sigma \in S_g}\left(\text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^g \#(\alpha_i \cap \beta_{\sigma(i)})\right) \\ &=\sum_{\sigma \in S_g}\left(\text{sgn}(\sigma) \prod_{i=1}^g \left(\sum_{x_i \in \alpha_i \cap \beta_{\sigma(i)}} s(x_i) \right) \right) \end{align}
and on the left,
\begin{align} \sum_{x\in \mathfrak{S}(H)}s(\mathbf{x}) &=\sum_{x\in \mathfrak{S}(H)}\text{sgn}(\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}) \prod_{i=1}^g s(x_i) \\ &= \sum_{\sigma \in S_g}\sum_{x_i \in \alpha_i \cap \beta_{\sigma(i)}} \text{sgn}(\sigma_{\mathbf{x}}) \prod_{i=1}^g s(x_i)  \end{align}
Could someone please confirm whether this looks good so far? I'm not sure whether or not I can factor out any of the signs, or why the sum and product would commute.

Update: I've come across a very useful reference, co-authored by the speaker himself - https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.6329. The set up is more clearly outlined there, but I am still not sure how he arrives at that computation on p.5...
